# Excel date formual

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data validation list cell that allows a drop down menu of all the months of the year.  I have another formula that is showing day 1, day 2, day 3 etc of the month based on whatever month is chosen above. 


[image: Screenshot of my worksheet]


Day 1 formula is: `="1-"&B1`   *<--B1 is where the month drop down is.* 
Day 2 formula is: `=B5+1`
Day 3 formula is: `=C5+1`
etc...

The problem I'm running into, is the data that it is pulling from is not recognizing Day 1.  How do I write a formula that will populate day 1 of whatever month is chosen?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make this an actual date using DATEVALUE:

```
=DATEVALUE("1-"&B1)
```

and then format the cells to `d-mmm`.